# max_input_size increased but dont allow me to post all inputs

Tags: php, laravel

I changed my php.ini to 
max_input_size 5000

post_max_size = 50M

but still not working

my form have 33 inputs per line and have 42 lines
so that give me 1386 inputs, and when I see my input array dont have all the data
I just get about 35 lines of that 42.

that's the main table:

```
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>IDENTIFICAÇÃO DA PEÇA</th>
        <th>Nº DA JUNTA</th>
        <th>POSIÇÃO</th>
        <th>DIÂMETRO Ø</th>
        <th>Espessura Menor</th>
        <th>Espessura Maior</th>
        <th>REFORÇO</th>
        <th>METAL BASE</th>
        <th>METAL ADIÇÃO</th>
        <th>SINETE RAIZ</th>
        <th>SINETE ACABAMENTO</th>
        <th>NORMA</th>
        <th>NIVEL INSPEÇÃO</th>
        <th>PROCEDIMENTO</th>
        <th>DFF</th>
        <th>DFO</th>
        <th>TÉCNICA</th>
        <th>TEMPO DE FONTE EXPOSTA</th>
        <th>IQI</th>
        <th>CHANFRO</th>
        <th>QUANTIDADE FILME</th>
        <th>FILME CLASSE</th>
        <th>FILME DIMENSÃO</th>
        <th>OBSERVAÇÃO</th>
        <th>PROCESSO</th>
        <th>EXCLUIR ITEM?</th>
```

my inputs text/hidden are like this:

```
<td><input class="input_informacao" type="text" name="progs[{{ $programacao->cod }}][item]" id="item" size="1" value="{{ $programacao->item }}"></td>
```

my selects are laravel blade select:

```
   <td>
    {{ Form::select("progs[".$programacao->cod."][tecnica]", array(
                '' => 'Selecione',
                'PS-VS' => 'PS-VS',
                'PD-VS' => 'PD-VS',
                'PD-VD' => 'PD-VD',
                'PS-VS/P' => 'PS-VS/P'), 
                $

programacao->tecnica , array('class' => 'input_informacao', 'id' => 'tecnica')) }}
</td>
```

I'v 42 inputs, id 14 to 55; and when I die dump the input var dont post all the data.
a example of input,

```
47 => 
        array (size=28)
          'cod' => string '47' (length=2)
          'item' => string '12' (length=2)
          'identificacao' => string 'BC. INFERIOR PAINEL 17' (length=22)
          'junta' => string '10' (length=2)
          'posicao' => string '-' (length=1)
          'diametro' => string '33,7' (length=4)
          'espmenor' => string '3,81' (length=4)
          'espmaior' => string '3,81' (length=4)
          'reforco' => string '-' (length=1)
          'metalbase' => string '' (length=0)
          'metaladicao' => string '' (length=0)
          'sineteraiz' => string '' (length=0)
          'sineteacabamento' => string '' (length=0)
          'norma' => string '' (length=0)
          'nivel' => string '' (length=0)
          'procedimento' => string '' (length=0)
          'dff' => string '' (length=0)
          'dfo' => string '' (length=0)
          'tecnica' => string 'PD-VD' (length=5)
          'tempoexposicao' => string '00:00:00' (length=8)
          'iqi' => string '10ISO16-13' (length=10)
          'chanfro' => string '' (length=0)
          'qtdfilmes' => string '3' (length=1)
          'filmeclasse' => string 'I' (length=1)
          'filmedimensao' => string 'A' (length=1)
          'observacao' => string '' (length=0)
          'processo' => string '' (length=0)
          'item_excluido' => string 'N' (length=1)
      49 => 
        array (size=7)
          'cod' => string '49' (length=2)
          'item' => string '12' (length=2)
          'identificacao' => string 'BC. INFERIOR PAINEL 17' (length=22)
          'junta' => string '10' (length=2)
          'posicao' => string '-' (length=1)
          'diametro' => string '33,7' (length=4)
          'espmenor' => string '3,81' (length=4)
```

somebody know how could I solve this?

ps: and I'm also use laravel 4.1
thanks !!

Comment: There are other settings to configure, like max_post_size. Are you submitting via GET or POST? GET is truncated to a certain # of characters.

Comment: you will likely need to also modify the post_max_size param in php.ini. Depending on what you are trying to do. In the future please include code so we have some idea what you are trying to do. for all me know this could be 1386 inputs that are image uploads which would be a different case then just text.

Comment: i changed max_post_size to 50M and input_max_size to 10k and upload limit also to 50M, but nothing happened, I'm using vagrant